# cuda 5.0 dynamic parallelism error: ptxas fatal . unresolved extern function 'cudaLaunchDevice

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

I am using tesla k20 with compute capability 35 on Linux with CUDA 5.With a simple child kernel call it gives a compile error : `Unresolved extern function cudaLaunchDevice`

My command line looks like:

```
nvcc --compile -G -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_35 , code=sm_35 -x cu -o fill.cu fill.o
```

I see `cudadevrt.a` in lib64.. Do we need to add it or what coukd be done to resolve it? Without child kernel call everything works fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must explicitly compile with relocatable device code enabled and link the device runtime library in order to use dynamic parallelism. So your compilation command must include `--relocatable-device-code true` and the *linking* command (which you haven't shown us) should include `-lcudadevrt`.

This procedure is described in detail in the "TOOLKIT SUPPORT FOR DYNAMIC PARALLELISM" section of the Dynamic Parallelism Programming Guide pdf, available [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Dynamic_Parallelism_Programming_Guide.pdf).

Comment: i already added the library in eclipse cuda nvcc linker libraries but still it gives error.

Comment: Now command line looks nvcc --compile -G -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_35, code=sm_35 -x cu -o "fill.o" ../fill.cu -lcudadevrt  i tried both library path and copying cudadevrt lib to project file. still error exist..

Comment: @Zahid: The command you are writing is only compiling device code to an object file. You need to add the -lcudadevrt to the command which links the application. Did you read the pdf I linked to?

Comment: Its not reaching to nvcc linker. It stop after compile giving error. Do i need to select device linker mode as .. separate compilation?

Comment: @Zahid: check my edit. I missed the fact you were not compiling with relocatable device code enabled. Add `-rdc=true` to the compile statement and -lcudavert to the linking statement.

Comment: Thank you so much talonmies. compiled successfull. We can use separate compile mode in eclipse for same purpose. But now it has issues with launch and debug. thank a million for support.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps I'm somewhat off topic, but I would like to mention that I had the same issue under Windows/Visual Studio 2010 and I have solved the problem using the last comment by talonmies in few steps.

```
1) View -> Property Pages
2) Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Common -> Generate Relocatable Device Code -> Yes (-rdc=true)
3) Configuration Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Device -> Code Generation -> compute_35,sm_35
4) Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies -> cudadevrt.lib
```

I hope that this information is useful.