# Unknown nvlink error

Tags: c++, c, cuda, linker

I'm getting this whenever I try to build my project:

```
make all
Building target: CudaMaster
Invoking: NVCC Linker
nvcc --relocatable-device-code=true -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -link -o  "CudaMaster"  ./Demodulator.o ./DifferentialDecoder.o ./Downsampler.o ./FileReader.o ./Filter.o ./GPURuntimeMetric.o ./Kernels.o ./PreambleDetector.o ./SampleComparator.o ./Samples.o ./TestBench.o ./main.o   
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to 'cudaGetParameterBuffer'
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to 'cudaLaunchDevice'
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to 'cudaDeviceSynchronize'
make: *** [CudaMaster] Error 255
```

I have literally no idea why.  I'm using the Nsight plugin for Eclipse and using the CUDA 5 toolkit in RHEL Server 6.3 with a Tesla K20 GPGPU.  I'm also using dynamic parallelism, which I think is causing the problem.  I searched around, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888804/cuda-5-0-dynamic-parallelism-error-ptxas-fatal-unresolved-extern-function-cu), which I feel confirms my theory, but he was doing it from the terminal, so it's not exactly the same.  What do I need to do to have it build while using Eclipse?  Is there an option I'm missing that needs to be set or something?

Thanks!

Comment: add `-lcudadevrt` to your command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for dynamic parallelism to work you need to link against cudadevrt

in nsight you do it like that:

- go to Project menu -> Properties -> Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> NVCC Linker
- append "-lcudadevrt" to the string of "Command" (i.e. "nvcc -lcudadevrt")